# Enable/Disable Sharing (SSH/File) Based on Network?

Tags: network, wifi, ssh, sharing

Is it possible to enable and disable the Sharing features (ssh, file sharing, etc) based on the current network?

For example, I want file sharing and SSH to be enabled on my trusted home network.  However, I don't want these enabled when I am connected to untrusted public networks.

Is it possible to set up this policy?  To differentiate between a home and public network?

I don't think this occurs by default because I often see shared folders and shared itunes libraries on public networks.  While they are protected by passwords, I would rather be completely sealed up on public networks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) for this. It allows you to control your context, like home and other, and set actions for it: when 'enter' home context, enable file sharing, when 'leave' home context, disable file sharing.